# Scala-like underscore typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Just for fun, I was trying to fiddle together a Scala-like underscore in typescript.
What I want to achieve is that instead of writing `.map(x => x.myProp)`, I can just do `.map(_.myProp)`. The implementation is rather straightforward using Proxies, the typing however not so much.

```js
type Rec<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = T[K]

export const _ = new Proxy<
  Record<string, <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(o: T) => Rec<T, K>>
>(
  {},
  {
    get(target: any, p: string) {
      return <T extends object, K extends typeof p & keyof T>(obj: T) => obj[p as K] as Rec<T, K>
    }
  }
)
```

This gets me to the point where I can see the correct type passed through map in the next chain, but I have a hard time locking down the myProp type:

[image]

And that's where I got stuck. I thought one could maybe type the Proxy with <any extends infer R ? R: never> but then the R cannot be used to narrow down the property in the get handler.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Added a [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+jAvDMBTA7jACgJxADwE8AeAKBhgCVVQcATY6HASzAHMAaGYgFRlXxRUYOhBggARgCsaULgGl+g4aJgBrVIRAAzGDwB8AChAAuPQEok+vQG15AXX2kj5GAG8Avh1dvXFNqhQhlAAhjgBUGYhYIRcAA5mTKxslr4U6TA4gQCuOGDcfAJCImKSMsByMIpFKmJQhHGoOjBxMABk6prNBsbSZjyWiNZlNq0hYg4w47YOfjAergvmpKT1jTAAkkIAtkjuc2Ah26iJUCzsc8x0ZmDZ2xKoOKQLpKCQsGE4Zluo2zb2exsbkOxzMAHIAIIiLLjMFcK5mACMXncIJOMDBPEkzFh8OuMAATCjgUd0WCsIFHnCYAiYABmYlo8EAERCADcrtTaQAWDz2FZvaAoUkAGWYQuQnwAdNsQnFDHApWjzDK5YZ8FYYPgVVIQKxDNSwctXuAICAADaoKXmkBsQxosXQZZAA)

As you can see in the second identity map `x` is `string | number` instead of 'string'. If changing the first map to `_.id` x should be just `number`

Comment: A minimun reproducable example would be helpful. One which shows what you have so far and how usage is intended.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible, but workarounds are available. Of course, I'd love to be proven wrong, but in the meantime, you could try making `_("friends")` work first.

Comment: A [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) function (e.g. _\`key\` ) would be a similarly concise mechanism, but [it appears that inference is not currently possible from the raw string portion of the argument](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33304).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion using `_("...")` instead:

```
const _ = <K extends string>(key: K) => {
  return <V>(obj: Record<K, V>) => obj[key];
};
```

It's pretty simple and it works.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mx8BBm)

Comment: ye that's pretty much what ramda has with `prop("...")`